# Exposing an api in a web page with browserify standalone - getting not defined error in Firefox

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

I am new to node and JavaScript stuff. I want to access an API in a web page. I followed [this guide](http://www.ryandaigle.com/a/expose-javascript-api-with-browserify) but I can't get it to work. Firefox always tells me that **MyLibrary is not defined**. I tried around but can't get it to work. WebStorm IDE however did recognize it correctly in the code editor. So I don't know why it does not work in FF.

I have a file called **readprotocoljson.js** which I want to expose in an webpage, I want to acess the contents

```
import {sequenceOf, asSequence, emptySequence, generateSequence} from 'sequency';
module.exports = MyLibrary;

function MyLibrary(){}
MyLibrary.prototype.readLogFile=

function readlogfile() {
    loadJSON(function(response) {
        // Parse JSON string into object
        var actual_JSON = JSON.parse(response);

        asSequence(actual_JSON.Frames); //just for testing
        return actual_JSON.Frames;
    });

};
```

I followed the guide and created a new file **exportedModules.js**

```
module.exports = require('./readprotocoljson.js')
```

In my html I include the lib with

```
<script src="dist/exportedModules.js"><script>
<body>
    <script>
        var exportedModules = new MyLibrary();
        var all_frames = exportedModules.readLogFile();
    </script>
</body>
```

I execute it via **gulpfile.babel.js**  and I run it with **--standalone** option
My gulpfile looks like this:

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
import browserSync from 'browser-sync';
import browserify from 'gulp-task-browserify';

gulp.task('scripts', browserify({
    src: 'exportedModules.js',
    dest: 'dist',
    uglify: false,
    sourcemaps: true,
    standalone: 'MyLibrary',
    watch: {
        callback: browserSync.reload
    }
}));
```

My **package.json i**nlcudes the following dependenices:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "sequency": "latest",
    "browser-sync": "latest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-node-modules": "0.0.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0",
    "browserify": "latest",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-task-browserify": "latest"
  }
```

Comment: your files are `.json` not `.js`?

Comment: No, they are all js files. I just typed it wrong here

Comment: what is `readprotocoljson.js` that you require? do you mean `readprotocol.js`?

Comment: The files are all correct. I just corrected it in the post here., it's readprotocoljson

Comment: I still don't know what the error was/is, but I now switched to webpack and it works as expected.